# Tomcat behind Nginx reverse proxy - Recipient endpoint doesn't match with SAML response

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, nginx-reverse-proxy, spring-saml

Here are the components:

1. Spring MVC web app on tomcat
2. Azure AD IdP
3. Nginx reverse proxy

The SSO works without Nginx reverse proxy, hence i suppose the configuration for my app and AzureID is done correctly.
However i faced an error when nginx reverse proxy comes into play. Here's the log error

> 2021-02-17 19:05:14,690 172.18.0.2 /saml/SSO/alias/my_app [ERROR] org.opensaml.common.binding.decoding.BaseSAMLMessageDecoder - SAML message intended destination endpoint https://myapp.example.com/saml/SSO/alias/my_app did not match the recipient endpoint http://myapp.example.com/saml/SSO/alias/my_app;

Not sure why http instead of https is passed upstream to tomcat. I followed the best practice to setup SSL for nginix. Here's the config for myapp

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name   _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name myapp.example.com;

    access_log logs/myapp.access;
    error_log logs/myapp.error error;

    location / {

        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host    $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server  $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   https;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_pass          http://myapp:8180/;
    }
}
```

Any i missing anything? Any comments will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: Quick solution**
The issue was that tomcat does not process the X-Forwarded-Proto to the servlets. There are few ways to resolve this. The easiest is to add scheme attribute to the <Connector> in server.xml

You can refer to tomcat config document on the attributes definition.
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" 
               proxyName="myapp.example.com"
               proxyPort="443"
               **scheme="https"** />
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that tomcat does not process the X-Forwarded-Proto to the servlets. There are few ways to resolve this. The easiest is to add scheme attribute to the Connector tag in server.xml

You can refer to tomcat config document on the attributes definition. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" 
               proxyName="myapp.example.com"
               proxyPort="443"
               **scheme="https"** />
```